Angular ./ ASP.NET Core SignalR message not receive to user
In my project, I will create a private conversation system between users with SignalR using Angular and ASP.NET Core. SignalR connection is successful and message sending is successful. However, the message is not delivered to the user to whom I sent the message. What could be the reason?
I want messages to be sent only between two users by id and not to a group.
This is my ChatHub class which is in the server side
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace FineMaster.Server.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendPrivateMessage(int senderId, int receiverId, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Client(receiverId.ToString()).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", senderId, message);
        }
    }
}

And this is my service.ts file which is on the client side
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  private message$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:7235/chat')
      .build();
  }

  async startConnection(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.hubConnection.start();
      console.log('SignalR connected!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting to SignalR:', error);
    }
  }

  sendMessage(senderId: number, receiverId: number, message: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.hubConnection.invoke('SendPrivateMessage', senderId, receiverId, message)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(senderId + 'says ' + message + " to " + receiverId);
        return true; // Indicate successful message sending
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        return false; // Indicate error during message sending
      });
  }

  onReceiveMessage(): Observable<string> {
    this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (messages) => {
      this.message$.next(messages);
    });
    return this.message$.asObservable();


  }
}


and this is component page where i want to get message
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const storedUser = this.cookieService.get("userInfo");
    if (storedUser) {
      var storedUserJson = JSON.parse(storedUser);
      this.currentUserID = storedUserJson.id;
    }
    this.chatService.startConnection();


    this.chatService.onReceiveMessage().subscribe(response => {
      console.log("bişey geldi: ", response);
    });
  }

in console the receiver id sender id and message is true

13 and 16 not the correct connectionId.

You are using wrong user id when call Clients.Client(should_use_connectionId) method.
We can use ConnectedUsers below to manage users and connections.
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>? ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

You can refer my sample code like below, or use custom UserConnectionManager.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SignalRMiddleawre.Hubs
{
    public partial class MainHub : Hub
    {
        #region Connection
        /// <summary>
        /// Use ConcurrentDictionary to save connected users's id and connectionId
        /// </summary>
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>? ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

        /// <summary>
        ///  OnConnectedAsync method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// 
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            if (userid == null || userid.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("user not loged in, can't connect signalr service");
                return;
            }
            Trace.TraceInformation(userid + "connected");
            // save connection
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds = null;
            ConnectedUsers?.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
            if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
            {
                existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
            }
            existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            ConnectedUsers?.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnDisconnectedAsync
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            // save connection
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds= new List<string>() ;

            ConnectedUsers?.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);

            existUserConnectionIds?.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

            if (existUserConnectionIds?.Count == 0)
            {
                List<string> garbage;
                ConnectedUsers?.TryRemove(userid, out garbage);
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
        #endregion

    }
}

